# Seemingly easy Fleming's question, repeatedly getting wrong answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrons, conductors

Easy question deceived me and my budding physics ego. I solved the question in the following way:

1. Took the field to be parallel to and opposite to the velocity of the electron as that was a fact our teacher had told us.
2. Considered the current to be downwards, as the current upwards is conventional and for the electron current should be downwards.
3. Used our darling Fleming's left hand rule to find that the force was into the page.

The answer shockingly stated that the force was downwards. Working backwards, if the force is downwards, and if the current should actually be taken to the left, as the opposite direction to which the electron travels, then that would mean the question assumes the  field to be into the page which makes no sense to me.
All help, clues, solutions are greatly greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What does the magnetic field of a current carrying wire look like?

Comment: Remember the force isn't  v×B, it's qv×B. Q is negative so force flips

Comment: Personally I'd avoid Fleming left hand rule with all of its variants, and use the definition of the cross product, and then manually flip the force depending on whether q is negative or positive

Comment: @jensenpaull thank you for that hint. So if we must flip the force, and we know the field is into the page using right hand rule, and the current is upwards, the force should be to the left. Flipped, it would be to the right. But none of those options are listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider it like this: conventional current is the flow of positive charge, which is considered **opposite** to flow of negative charge(here, electrons). Flemings left hand rule is valid for conventional current. By using right hand thumb rule, you will see magnetic field is inwards. Now apply left hand rule to conventional current and you will get the result.

And just like Jensen Paul said in the comments, you can use the formula to see that on putting the value of $q$ to be negative in $\vec{F}=q(\vec{v}×\vec{B})$, you get the sign to be negative so the force acts in direction opposite to what it would have acted had the charge been positive.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to you, finally was able to get the answer. I was fooled by the current they had given and did not realise that it should be to the opposite side of the electron flow.

Comment: @SnehalBhadani glad I could help you! If the answer has satisfied you then you can mark this to be the accepted answer by clicking the check/tick mark beside my answer

Comment: done :) Tried upvoting it too but didn't have enough reputation, still new here